# How do I go from LLVM IR to Solana BPF?

Tags: bpf, core-technology

Suppose I already have some LLVM IR - how do I turn this into Solana BPF?

And what happens if my LLVM IR is doing things that Solana doesn't support, like Rust hashmaps?